# Convert ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(?, ?), 4326) to Java @Entity

Tags: spring, geospatial

I have this SQL statement (which has been shortened)

```
INSERT INTO incidents (lat, lon, geom)
VALUES (?, ?, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(?, ?), 4326));
```

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE vessel_incidents
(
  id                 BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  lat                DOUBLE PRECISION,
  lon                DOUBLE PRECISION,
  geom               GEOMETRY
);
```

which is used by a Java PreparedStatement:

```
1st ? = lat (Double)
2nd ? = lon (Double)
3rd ? = lat (Double)
4th ? = lon (Double)
```

This works well enough but we are shifting to Spring this is my entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "incidents")
public class IncidentEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    private Double lat;

    private Double lon;

    @Column(name = "geom", columnDefinition = "GEOMETRY")
    private String geometry;
}
```

This is the value for the column "0101000020E6100000ABAAAAAAAAAA274000000000000013C0" (that's why I used String)

Since we are using @Repository, how can I create the geometry string? the current way is to use

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(?, ?), 4326) in a java PreparedStatement.
```

Is there a java class that is equivalent to ST_MakePoint and ST_SetSRID, that can be used in the @Entity/@Repository?

Thanks.